# iOS App Private Distribution using redemption links

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, apple-business-manager

We are planning to distribute our app to certain clients using iOS Private Distribution redemption links. I have gathered all the information from Creating Apple Business manager account to downloading the redemption links from the business manager account.

I have enrolled myself in Apple Business manager account, waiting for apple approval on the same. Before going ahead i have the below questions

1. Does each redemption link work only for a single user or multiple users can use the link to download the app.?
2. How do we keep the Redemption link secure.?
3. Can the Apple Business manager account gives more analytics on our app installations and distribution process.?
4. Once the app is approved and released, does the subsequent builds should go again apple review process? How does the user know the app updates has been released with newer version?

Answer (score 1):

1. Each redemption code or link is only valid for a single user. It is the same as if you gifted an app to a user. Once they redeem the code the app is "owned" by their Apple ID.  This is one of the major problems with using redemption codes for custom apps; If it is redeemed using a personal Apple ID then you can never remove the app from the user, even if they leave the organisation.
2. The redemption link itself is not secure.  You need to consider the process by which you will send redemption links to users to ensure that they reach the intended user, such as sending it to their work email address
3. Apple Business manager tells you how many of your "purchased" apps have been redeemed.  Once a code is redeemed the user can install the app on any device that has their Apple ID logged in. This is not visible in Apple Business Manager
4. The review process is the same as for an App Store app; new releases are reviewed as with any app update.  Updates will appear in the user's "available updates" list in the App Store app and will be installed automatically if the user has selected that option.

Using redemption links/codes is not best practice for custom apps. It is strongly recommended that you use an MDM to manage deployment of custom apps to devices.